# pandas getting a value from a key that contains a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, screen-scraping

how will i just get 'Spongebob Squarepants' from this:

```
[{'characters': [{'id': 'Spongebob Squarepants', 'name': 'Spongebob Squarepants'}]}]
```

i've tried doing

```
data['characters']['id']
```

and

```
data['characters']['name']
```

but it resulted in the error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

And when I saved it to a dataframe the character column becomes this whole string

```
[{'id': 'Spongebob Squarepants', 'name': 'Spongebob Squarepants'}]}]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data['characters'] is a list, so you'd have to do:

```
data['characters'][0]['id']
```

Comment: thank you so much! it's actually part of a larger list so i used to for loop and resolved it!! what i did for future reference: 

for y in x['characters']:
            row['nick_char'] = y['id']